# Find all array elements for time t

Tags: javascript, arrays, search

Given an array whose elements are objects in the form:

```
{
    "description": "foo",
    "startTime": 0,
    "endTime": 100
}
```

I need to find all elements for which `startTime <= t <= endTime`.

- `(endTime - startTime) >= 100`, but there is no explicit upper bound on the time differential, nor is the differential necessarily the same for each object in the array. `startTime` can be negative.
- `arr[i].startTime <= arr[i + 1].startTime`, but the same is **not** necessarily true for `endTime`.
- `description` is **not** unique, not even necessarily for a given time span.
- Times correspond to milliseconds in a video, which can easily be an hour or more. If a 1hr video has 100ms duration objects for its entire length, that's 36,000 array elements to filter. Depending on the video, there could easily be a dozen objects for a single 100ms timespan.

My current solution is a simple `Array.prototype.filter` call:

```javascript
video.getCurrentTime((s) => { // library function; s=current time in seconds of the video
  const ms = Math.floor(s * 1000);
  const itemsAtTime = metadata.filter((o) => { // metadata is array of objects
    const start = o.startTime;
    const end = o.endTime;
    return start <= ms && ms <= end;
  });

  // ...

  for (let obj of itemsAtTime) {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```

As best as I can tell, `filter` is implemented as a linear search. Is there any better algorithm available to achieve my goal? Perhaps some variant of binary search?

On my 2 minute demo video/metadata that I'm testing with, most of the `filter` calls complete in about 0.7ms. However, a number of them take 1-5ms, and I've tracked some extreme outliers like 11ms or even 33ms. My "do stuff" loop usually completes in 0.1ms, with heavy load taking 4ms and outliers at 12ms. Worst of all, the `getCurrentTime` function is asynchronous, generally taking 1-5ms between calling it and having the callback get called, with heavy load in the neighborhood of 50-60ms and outliers upwards of 500ms. Considering this code is in a function being passed to `setInterval`, with the interval running while the video is playing (currently with a 250ms interval, but ultimately I think I'd like to use a 100ms interval or less), I'm worried about the performance when I start using hour-plus duration videos.

Comment: The only way you can go faster than linear time is to have nothing to do at all.

Comment: @peteb maybe you could go `log(n)`, for example? That's faster than linear (n).

Comment: @LuanNico Yes, but then the items for which he wants to filter would need to be sorted. If they're not being inserted in a sorted way then you have the overhead of that.

Comment: @peteb they are sorted by startTime.

Comment: @BrianS thats a key bit of information. Also size of the collection would be a nice piece of information as well.

Comment: You could make a binary search to find the first item where `startTime <=  ms`. Then you can filter linearly from that index onwards. That's the best I can think of.

Comment: @peteb ... I included that information. `arr[i].startTime <= arr[i + 1].startTime`. Size of the collection is heavily dependent on the video it's associated with, but I gave an example of a 1hr video having 36,000 objects in it.

Comment: @BrianS Can't believe I missed that lol. You could keep splitting the set you're looking at using recursion adding to a separate collection as you go or keeping track of the flagged indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a binary search to find the first item where `startTime <= ms`. Then you can filter linearly from that index onward. That's the best I can think of.

So, something like:

```
const binaryWhereMin = function(arr, ms) {
  // write your function that returns the index of first element start <= ms
};

let index = binaryWhereMin(arr, ms);
let result = arr.splice(index, arr.length).filter(/* your filter */);
```

I can't see a better way, since ends are not sorted.

Here there is a [binary search example](http://oli.me.uk/2013/06/08/searching-javascript-arrays-with-a-binary-search/). but you will need to alter it not to search for a specific element (it's not going to be as efficient!, but I believe it's still better than what you have).